# WPF Grid Updating Issue

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am adding an item to my datasource that is bound to a datagrid, but the UI is not updating to show the new item. Here is my code.

```
   DBContainer ctx = new DBContainer();
    private void btnAddNewDesignator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DESIGNATOR a = new DESIGNATOR();
        a.DesignatorName = txtDesignator.Text;
        a.TXFreq = txtTX.Text;
        a.RXFreq = txtRX.Text;
        ctx.AddToDESIGNATORs(a);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        dgDesignators.Items.Refresh(); 

    }
    private void btnAddNewDesignator_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgDesignators.ItemsSource = ctx.DESIGNATORs;
    }
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="225" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,230,0,0" Name="dgDesignators" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="602" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Designator"   Binding="{Binding Path=DesignatorName,Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TX Frequency" Binding="{Binding Path=TXFreq,Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RX Frequency" Binding="{Binding Path=RXFreq,Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="In Use" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

As you can see I am refreshing, I have also tried setting the ItemSource to null first, and then rebinding it, but to no avail. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can we see your xaml?

Comment: How are you setting the `DataSource`? You should really use a `Property` binding with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: With  dgDesignators.ItemsSource = ctx.DESIGNATORs;

Answer (score 0):

Button Event Handler:

```
private void btnAddNewDesignator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DESIGNATOR a = new DESIGNATOR();
    a.DesignatorName = txtDesignator.Text;
    a.TXFreq = txtTX.Text;
    a.RXFreq = txtRX.Text;
    ctx.AddToDESIGNATORs(a);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    designatorDataSource = ctx.DESIGNATOR.ToList();
}
```

ItemsSourceProperty:

```
private List<DESIGNATOR> _designatorDataSource = new List<DESIGNATOR>();
public List<DESIGNATOR designatorDataSource {
    get {
        return _designatorDataSource;
    }
    set {
        _designatorDataSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("designatorDataSource");
    }
}
```

Then you bind your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgDesignators" ItemsSource={Binding designatorDataSource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</DataGrid>
```

---

Edit:
Adding `INotifyPropertyChanged`, have your class extend `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Example:
    using System.ComponentModel;
    public class MyClass : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged

Add the Property Change Event

```
#region Property Change Event
/// <summary>
/// Occurs when a property is changed
/// </summary>
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

/// <summary>
/// Raises the <see cref="PropertyChanged"/> for a given 
/// property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName"></param>
protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
    // Get the handler
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

    // Check that the event handler is not null
    if(null != handler) {
    // Fire the event
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Except OnPropertyChanged means the class needs to derive from INotifyPropertyChange, so This would have to go in a new data context class correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DBContainer ctx = new DBContainer();
private void btnAddNewDesignator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DESIGNATOR a = new DESIGNATOR();
    a.DesignatorName = txtDesignator.Text;
    a.TXFreq = txtTX.Text;
    a.RXFreq = txtRX.Text;
    ctx.AddToDESIGNATORs(a);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    dgDesignators.Items.Refresh(); 

}
private void btnAddNewDesignator_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dgDesignators.ItemsSource = ctx.DESIGNATORs.ToList();
}
```

I don't suggest this kind of code in WPF, try doing it in an MVVM pattern and it should be easier to implement and all you need to do is make a class that will act as the DataContext of the DataGrid and make that class implement **INotifyPropertyChange**